# AdMob click Crash App

Tags: android, crash, admob

I add the AdMob on my application and it´s working, but when I click to test the Ad, my Application crash, but the Browser popup and open the link of the ad.

So what it could be?

Follow the cat log:

>

```
 04-23 14:13:07.460: I/Ads(1440): onPresentScreen()
04-23 14:13:07.460: I/Ads(1440): onLeaveApplication()
04-23 14:13:07.602: W/ResourceType(1440): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010099
04-23 14:13:07.602: W/ResourceType(1440): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009a
04-23 14:13:07.610: W/ResourceType(1440): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009b
04-23 14:13:07.610: W/ResourceType(1440): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010099
04-23 14:13:07.610: W/ResourceType(1440): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009a
04-23 14:13:07.610: W/ResourceType(1440): Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009b
04-23 14:13:07.642: D/AndroidRuntime(1440): Shutting down VM
04-23 14:13:07.650: W/dalvikvm(1440): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:671)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2485)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2545)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1425)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     ... 21 more
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.initTitle(ActionBarView.java:572)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setDisplayOptions(ActionBarView.java:401)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:202)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     ... 24 more
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     ... 34 more
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:422)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:364)
04-23 14:13:07.720: E/AndroidRuntime(1440):     ... 37 more
04-23 14:13:07.980: D/dalvikvm(1440): GC_CONCURRENT freed 353K, 6% free 7844K/8263K, paused 4ms+2ms
04-23 14:13:09.370: D/webviewglue(1440): nativeDestroy view: 0x203140
```

---

This i what i Put in my XML file:

> 

```
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXX"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

---

I am using SDK 18, android version it´s 3.2.

For AdMob SDK it´s 6.0.

Some one have any idea?

Thanks.

---

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2707)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2767)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1534)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
... 21 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.initTitle(ActionBarView.java:726)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setDisplayOptions(ActionBarView.java:563)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:232)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:503)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:442)
... 37 more
```

Comment: Emulator or device?  Which version?  Are you overriding `onPresentScreen()` and doing anything special?

Comment: Emulator, Platform 3.2 API Level 13.
I don´t change anything on method onPresentScreen(). The first two lines on catlogs, it´s green, just information.
I do not put anything on the *.java file, just on XML, the code I put in the first post. Nothing special.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting that crash running a 3.2 emulator.  I wonder if it was just a bad ad (like download ad or something) that doesn't work on an emulator.  Can you try adding `ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"` to your XML layout (to request test ads on the emulator) and try clicking the test ad to see if you get the same issue?

Comment: I put this ads:testDevice, but the error still there, even in my Mobile Nexus S, I got this error too. I do not found no one else having this issue too. I sent the error to my account on android console. Look: **bold**
UnsupportedOperationException
em TypedArray.getColor()**bold**

Comment: I'm getting the same stack in my app on production. I've never seen it on my devices, the vast majority do not have a problem. I would like to eliminate the problem.